# Get specific string in sentence that doesn't include a specific word in front using REGEX?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a table with the underlying dummy data and would like to get a TRUE only when the text has the word "T-Rex" without the word Big in front.

**Ideal result:**

T-Rex           TRUE
Big T-Rex       FALSE
Monkey, T-Rex   TRUE

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sample Sheet Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tpW-MaTI5QXgAIMPJLoJ__9q9b-W6_v5zwrRJLnh1x4/edit?usp=sharing)

The task can be achieved using a multi-step workaround.

1. Match "T-Rex"
2. Match "Big T-Rex"
3. Identify records where 1. is true and 2. is false.

Unfortunately you cannot perform lookaheads and lookbehinds according to the [official documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt). The reason is discussed [here](https://github.com/google/re2/issues/156).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Did the multi-step workaround with an If-Statement.